# Как вывести дату в миллисекундах

Tags: java, android

Есть text view, как в него вывести дату и время в милли секундах, и можно ли вывести не дату устройства а unix ?

Comment: в каком классе у вас дата? Date, LocalDateTime, Calendar?

Comment: я пробовал через date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить unix timestamp из Date вам надо просто разделить миллисекунды на 1000.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
```

или проще:

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

---

перевести в строку можно так:

```
String time = Long.toString(unixTime);
```

или так:

```
String time = String.valueOf(unixTime);
```

Comment: а как его потом в строку для вывода в text view перевести?

Comment: дописал в ответ.

Comment: после запуска приложение вылетает, указывает на строку text.setText(time) пишет "является ссылкой на нулевой объект"

Comment: time не может быть null, так что только text. Инициализируйте его.